# Should I enable a feature I created on the same site?

Tags: 7, views, features

I created a view and some configurations and used features to save it into code. When doing so, I used the GUI interface and selected Advanced Features and named a file path (sites/all/modules/custom) and then clicked "generate". In doing so, the code was saved to that file path. It is now listed in the website under features > custom but it is listed as disabled.

What is the best practice for this scenario: should I enable it or keep it disabled since I clearly would like it to be active and part of the code? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you enable it. By that you keep track of changes you make on either development environment.

For example you edit some settings on your local dev site, then the activated feature will recognise the changes. Then you *recreate* the feature and commit the updated files to your repo. On live then you pull the file changes, which your activated feature there recognises as well.

Now you *revert* the feature on your live site and by that sync the settings you made on dev to live. All by having the feature activated on all instances you work with.

Comment: after doing all @leymannx very well explained, on live site, go to features and REVERT changes. A bit more explanation: on dev sites you allways do create/update features, on live sites you allways do "revert" features. that means on dev you make/buiilt the feature (from DB to code), on live site you do revert (code to DB).

Comment: Thanks for the excellent explanation. When I do "recreate" do I click advanced > "generate feature" again?

Comment: @Christia - Exactly :)